# Finding longest path using recursion with a set of rules

Tags: python, recursion, path-finding

For a bit of background, I'm not a computer scientist or programmer at all (studied physics in college where I picked up some python). My problem is to find the longest path through a matrix with a given set of rules. An example matrix would look something like this:

```
   [0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
   [0, 1, 0, 0, 0],
   [1, 1, 1, 0, 0],
   [0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
   [1, 0, 0, 1, 0],
```

The rules are as follows:

1. Start on a given "1" position, these are the valid positions.
2. Each jump must be to another valid position on the same row or column (it's possible to jump over "0"s).
3. Consecutive jumps can not be in the same direction (horizontal/vertical) unless jumping to and from a position on-diagonal.
4. No position can be used twice.

A valid path on the example matrix would look like:

```
(5,4),(5,1),(3,1),(3,3),(3,2),(2,2)
```

An invalid path because of rule #3 would look like:

```
(3,1),(3,2),(3,3)
```

whereas the following *is* possible:

```
(3,1),(3,3),(3,2)
```

Though I have a bit of experience with python, I've never tried recursion (I'm pretty sure that's how to tackle this), and I can't seem to find any help online that's at my level.

Comment: To ensure the problem is correctly understood: a valid move would be from one `1` to another `1`, but could be over many `0`s, correct? And by 'on-diagonal', do you mean to say you could jump onto a value on the diagonal and then continue on in the same direction on the other side of the diagonal?

It would probably help if you provided a smaller example matrix and the solution (calculated manually).

Comment: Thank you for the feedback. I made a couple edits that I hope clarify things a bit. Grismar, yes it's allowed to jump over 0s, and yes when you jump to a diagonal, you can jump off in the same direction (where normally that's forbidden).

Comment: In your problem statement you say 'Start on a given "1" position.' Does this mean the starting point is given as input to the routine, or does it mean that you want to  find the longest path regardless of the start position?

Answer (score 1):

There are several solutions for this. I would suggest first converting the grid to a more object oriented structure, i.e. an undirected graph with nodes for where there are 1s in the input.

Then I would distinguish three kinds of edges in that graph:

- Those where one of the end points is on a diagonal ("special" edges)
- Those where the above is not true, but nodes are in the same row
- Those where the above is not true, but nodes are in the same column

While recurring, you would always consider the special edges, and in addition to that, the edges that are in one of the other two sets of edges (based on the previous direction taken).

Here is an implementation:

```
class Node:
    def __init__(self, y, x, size):
        self.x = x
        self.y = y
        self.coord = (y, x)
        self.diagonal = x == y or size - 1 - y
        # Separate lists of neighbors: vertical, horizontal. 
        # Third list is for when this node or neighbor is on diagonal
        self.neighbors = [[], [], []] 

    def addNeighbor(self, node, direction):
        self.neighbors[direction].append(node)

class Maze:
    def __init__(self, grid):
        def addedge(a, b):
            direction = 2 if a.diagonal or b.diagonal else int(a.x == b.x)
            a.addNeighbor(b, direction)
            b.addNeighbor(a, direction)

        # alternative grid having Node references:
        self.nodes = [[None] * len(grid) for _ in grid] 
        colNodes = [[] for _ in grid]
        for y, row in enumerate(grid):
            rowNodes = []
            for x, cell in enumerate(row):
                if cell: # only create nodes for when there is a 1 in the grid
                    node = Node(y, x, len(grid))
                    for neighbor in rowNodes + colNodes[x]:
                        addedge(node, neighbor)
                    rowNodes.append(node)
                    colNodes[x].append(node)
                    self.nodes[y][x] = node

    def findpath(self, y, x):
        def recur(node, neighbors):
            visited.add(node)
            longest = [node.coord]
            # always visit "special" neighbors 
            #   (i.e. those on diagonal or all vert/horiz when node is on diagonal)
            for neighbor in node.neighbors[2] + neighbors:
                if not neighbor in visited:
                    # toggle direction when going further
                    path = recur(neighbor, node.neighbors[1-int(node.x == neighbor.x)])
                    if len(path) >= len(longest):
                        longest = [node.coord] + path
            visited.remove(node)
            return longest

        node = self.nodes[y][x]
        if not node:
            raise "Cannot start from that position"
        visited = set()
        # look in both directions of starting node
        return recur(node, node.neighbors[0] + node.neighbors[1]) 


grid = [
    [0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
    [0, 1, 0, 0, 0],
    [1, 1, 1, 0, 0],
    [0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
    [1, 0, 0, 1, 0]
]

maze = Maze(grid)
path = maze.findpath(2, 0)
print(path)  # output: [(2, 0), (2, 2), (2, 1), (1, 1)]

path = maze.findpath(4, 3)
print(path)  # output: [(4, 3), (4, 0), (2, 0), (2, 2), (2, 1), (1, 1)]
```

Note that the coordinates in this solution are zero-based, so the first row has number 0, ...etc.

See it run on [repl.it](https://repl.it/@trincottrincots/MazeJumps)

Answer (score 0):

You can use recursion with a generator:

```
d = [[0, 0, 0, 0, 0], [0, 1, 0, 0, 0], [1, 1, 1, 0, 0], [0, 0, 0, 0, 0], [1, 0, 0, 1, 0]]
_d = {1:lambda a, b:'f' if b[-1] > a[-1] else 'b', 0:lambda a, b:'u' if b[0] > a[0] else 'd'}
def paths(start, _dir, c = []):
   yield c
   _options = [(a, b) for a in range(len(d)) for b in range(len(d[0])) if (a, b) not in c and d[a][b]]
   if _options:
      for a, b in _options:
         if a == start[0] or b == start[-1]:
            r = _d[a == start[0]](start, (a, b))
            if _dir is None or r != _dir:
               yield from paths((a, b), r, c+[(a, b)])


print(max(list(paths((4, 3), None, [(4, 3)])), key=len))
```

Output:

```
[(4, 3), (4, 0), (2, 0), (2, 2), (2, 1), (1, 1)]
```